# custom dataset for image in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, conv-neural-network

I am trying to "custom dataset for image" using tensorflow 2.0
my directory structure is:
say (PetImage)as root directory which contains two classes: Cat and Dog which contains respective images.
/PetImage|
|Cat
| img1.jpg
| img2.jpg
| imgn.jpg
| ...

```
    |Dog | img1.jpg
         | img2.jpg
         | ig3.jpg
         | ig.jpg
         | ...
```

My code is as follows:
img_height = 64
img_width = 64

ds_train = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
"I:\Image\Data\kagglecatsanddogs_5340\PetImages",
labels="inferred",
label_mode="int",
color_mode="rgb",
image_size=(img_height, img_width),
shuffle=True,
seed=123,
validation_split=0.3,
subset="training",
interpolation="bicubic"
)

history = model.fit(ds_train, epochs=2)

Error:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Input is empty.
[[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
[[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1704]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tensorflow 2.0, there is no function - `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()` and even in the latest version of tensorflow 2.11 there is a function `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory()`

Refer to this link - "https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory"

Comment: Actually they are the same: https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/